# Select XML into a XML variable in SQL Server ignoring namespaces

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery, xml-namespaces

I have an XML file which looks something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Model format="1" heartbeat="PT2S">
lots of other nodes.
</Model>
```

I am doing the following before trying to shred the xml.  However, I only want the Model node and its Childrens etc.

```
Declare @xml XML
set @xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Model format="1" heartbeat="PT2S">
    lots of other nodes.
    </Model>'
```

How do i only get the Model Section ignoring the namespace/directive.  Directive in this instance of XML.

e.g. `Select @xml` (after removing the namespace/directive will give me the following)

```
<Model format="1" heartbeat="PT2S">
    lots of other nodes.
</Model>
```

I am using SQL Server 2014.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no namespaces mentioned in the XML sample you showed. So the title and question are confusing. Maybe by "namespace/directive" you mean the XML declaration, `<?xml...?>`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need:

```
Declare @xml XML
set @xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Model format="1" heartbeat="PT2S">
    lots of other nodes.
    </Model>'

SELECT @xml.query('Model')
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not quite understand what you mean:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Model format="1" heartbeat="PT2S">
<test>lots of other nodes.</test>
</Model>';

SELECT @xml;
```

returns

```
<Model format="1" heartbeat="PT2S">
    <test>lots of other nodes.</test>
</Model>
```

You speak about namespace and directive. This you should know:

#### Namespace

If your XML has got a namespace, you did not show this to us.

A namespace must either

- be specified (at least the default namespace `xmlsn`)
- or you must use a wildcard `*:`

#### Directive

Your `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` will be omitted in any case. internally SQL Server stores XML as unicode (which was `UTF-16`) and you are not allowed to set your own directive to an XML. That's why the simple `SELECT @xml` returns without the directive.

Sometimes people have troubles with special characters, which need a `N` before the literal, because in this case the engine complains due to the `UTF-8`:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Model>
Test
</Model>';
```

This just as a side note...

#### Read your XML

To get a result in any case you might try this:

Assuming an existing default namespace

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Model xmlns="tempTest" format="1" heartbeat="PT2S">
<test>lots of other nodes.</test>
</Model>';

SELECT @xml.query('/*:Model/*');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [value function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). This gets the contents of the model node as `nvarchar(max)`:

```
select @xml.value('/Model[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

Answer (score 0):

All nodes of Model as separate rows

```
Declare @xml XML;
set @xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Model format="1" heartbeat="PT2S">
    <lots/> <of/> <other/> <nodes./>
    </Model>';

select t.n.query('.')
from
@xml.nodes('Model/*') t(n);
```